# How do I deploy my Eclipse Tapestry web app project previously running in an embedded Jetty to a standalone Jetty?

Tags: hibernate, maven, xampp, jetty, tapestry

I have a Tapestry web application developed with Eclipse and previously running using the embedded Eclipse jetty using the Maven jetty plugin, more precisely using jetty:run.

The application is built using Tapestry 5.3.8 and uses Hibernate as a persistence provider. The back end is an XAMPP install.

When I export the application to a WAR, and put it inside the standalone jetty webapps folder and start jetty, I get the following error:

```
Render queue error in BeginRender[Index:layout.pagelink]: 
Error obtaining injected value for field somePkg.pages.TestData.em:
Unable to add method javax.persistence.EntityGraph createEntityGraph(java.lang.String) to
class $EntityManager_14cbc42cc34: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 15
```

`em` is the EntityManager which is injected when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is related to javassist / java 8. Later versions of tapestry (including 5.3.8) have ditched javassist in favour of ASM/Plastic.

Can you run the following from command line:

`mvn dependency:tree`

Look for javassist dependencies, from memory hibernate might use it. Probably best to see if the javassist version is compatible with java 8. If not you'll either need to use a jre8 compatible hibernate/javassist version or run with JRE7.

Comment: tapestry.ioc 5.3.8 uses javassist 3.12 which seems to be the culprit.

hibernate 4.3.8 uses javassist 3.18.1 which works.

Comment: Recommendation: Why not go the whole way like with the JavaScript engine and only use loose coupling for the bytecode stuff?

Comment: I'm surprised that tapestry-ioc 5.3.8 has a reference to javassist. Javassist should be removed all together from core tapestry. Can you try adding an [exclude](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) to the tapestry dependency so that javassist is excluded? You might need to explicitely declare a javassist version in your pom so that the explicit version is used (since nearest definition wins for dependency conflicts)

Comment: I really don't understand your comment regarding javascript / loose coupling

Comment: Re: javassist exclusion - It was enough to exclude the javassist in the tapestry-jpa dependency, as hibernate brought javassist 3.18.1 as a dependency with it.

Comment: So, as I said it wasn't tapestry core/IOC bringing in javassist, it was hibernate. It seems that the version of hibernate in tapestry-jpa is old. I would say the "proper" fix is to declare a recent version of hibernate in your own pom which will override transitive hibernate/javassist versions coming from tapestry-jpa (using maven's nearest definition wins strategy).